# Як приєднатися до адміністраторів Stackexchange Ukrainian Language?

Tags: discussion

Хочу долучитися до проєкту і перекласти інтерфейс з англійської. Бо куди годиться - українськомовна спільнота, а інтерфейс англійською).
Як долучитись до команди, чи може до перекладачів?

Comment: Для сайту найважливіше мати якісний вміст, а інтерфейс не має такого значення. Тому ви можете долучитись до розвитку сайту пишучи цікаві запитання і відповіді ;)

Answer (score 3):

Я згоден, що це ВЕЛИЧЕЗНИЙ недолік — що інтерфейс ukrainian.stackexchange.com (і його ме́та-сайту) лише англійською мовою.

Але ми всього-на-всього розділ більшого сайту (чи мережі сайтів — залежить від вибору термінології) StackExchange, тому обмежені його інфраструктурою і правилами. Розділ Ukrainian не має власних адміністраторів, лише модераторів (що мають обиратися спільнотою), і модератори розділу Ukrainian не мають впливу на інтерфейс сайту. Тобто:

1. Технічно — ми не можемо *самовільно* змінити інтерфейс розділу Ukrainian, лише *попросити* адміністраторів батьківського сайту (мережі) StackExchange про це.
2. Організаційно — ми були створені не як україномовний розділ, а як англомовний розділ про українську мову. (На той момент, та й може, і зараз, це був єдиний доступний шлях.) Я не певен, що нам дозволять переорієнтуватися на півдорозі.

Тобто я дуже сумніваюся, що нам дозволять зробити українськомовний інтерфейс. (Колись я уже спробував з'ясувати це. Але, якщо Ви маєте ентузіазм, ми можемо спробувати знову, раптом з того часу щось змінилося.)

Що ми точно можемо зробити (і що я давно хотів збирати, але не вистачало часу) — це розширення для браузера (у користувача, який встановить його, сайт буде показуватися в українському інтерфейсі). Я буду дуже радий, якщо Ви підготуєте переклади (а я оформлю їх у розширення). Але Ви самі розумієте, що корисність такого рішення дуже обмежена (небагато хто схоче встановлювати розширення в браузер лише задля того, щоб один сайт став показуватися українською).

P.S.: Якоїсь явної команди тут немає. Є просто відвідувачі/користувачі (чим більший користувач отримав рейтинг, тим більше в нього прав). Серед найактивніших користувачів обирають декількох модераторів (час від часу вони змінюються). От і все.

Answer (score -2):

**stackexchange.com** - це міжнародний ресурс з обміну знаннями, а не загальноукраїнський.

Comment: Мінус ставив не я. Але я не думаю, що міжнародність можна вважити аргументом _проти_ перекладу інтерфейсу (навіть навпаки — міжнародні ресурси часто мають якраз _багатомовні_ інтерфейси). Навіть на StackExchange є підсайти з неангломовним інтерфейсом: https://pt.stackoverflow.com, https://ja.stackoverflow.com, https://ru.stackoverflow.com, https://rus.stackexchange.com, https://es.stackoverflow.com (але НЯЗ у них інша ситіація, а нам так не можна).

Comment: Та поки будете перекладати, весь ресурс піде в мінус 

Comment: Не зрозумів, можете пояснити? Ви за те, щоб не перекладати зовсім, бо це займає забагато часу, — чи я не вгадав?

Comment: Який сенс перекладати інтерфейс для п'ятьох користувачів.